# R markdown Knit to HTML : Error in library(dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, rstudio, r-markdown

I am working on R markdown script (RStudio). Individual code chunk works but when i try to Knit to HTML , it throws error as "Error in library(dplyr) : there is no package called 'dplyr' Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> library"

code

````
##install library
```{r install pkg,include=FALSE,cache=TRUE}

install.packages("kableExtra",repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")

install.packages("dplyr", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")

install.packages("ggplot2", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")


```




```{r setup, include=FALSE}

library(knitr)

library(dplyr)

library(ggplot2)

```
````

Comment: why do you need to have the package installation inside your `.Rmd`? probably you already have them installed anyhow, no?

Comment: Yes , I already have them installed . I can remove installation section  and try but error i am getting is  for "library(dplyr)" loading .

Comment: If you still have the same problem, maybe it can help if you check the output of .libPaths() before loading dplyr and possibly adjust it?

Comment: I removed installer and added .libPaths(c(<>,<>)) in.Rmd file but still no luck . Getting same error .

Comment: knitting is generally done in a separate process, not the same session you're running.  You probably have `dplyr` installed in some local library and haven't told the session your document is running where to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Restart R 
You should manually install packages and then knit to HDML. Click Tools > Install Packages and then type in the packages